# Regex to capture url until a certain character

Tags: python, regex, capture, regex-group

With a url such as

> `https://search.yahoo.com/search?p=Fetty+Wap&amp;fr=fp-tts&`

I am using

```
pat = re.compile('<a href="(https?://.*?)".*',re.DOTALL)
```

as a search pattern.

I want to pick any url like the yahoo url above, but I want to capture the url up to the literal `?` in the actual url.

In other words I want to extract the url up to `?`, knowing that all the urls I'm parsing don't have the `?` character. In such a case I need to capture all of the url.

The above regex works and extracts the url but goes to the end of the url. How can I get it to stop at the first `?` it encounters, and keep going to the end if it doesn't encounter a `?`

Comment: can you add the code what you have tried to this question?

Comment: from os import system;system('cls')\n
from urllib import urlopen;import re\n
# look for lines like <a href="http://url+sometext(stopCaptureAtLiteral?"> Some Text </a>\n
count = 0\n
pat = re.compile(r'<a href="(https?://(.+?\?|.+?))".*',re.DOTALL)\n
nh = urlopen('http://www.yahoo.com')\n
for line in nh:\n
    if re.search(pat,line):\n
        count += 1\n
        print count,re.search(pat,line).group(1)\n
 Please look at the comment want to captr the anchor tag pull out a url but\n
only till the ? if there is one in the url else the whole url\n

Comment: sorry I can't figure out how to do a line break I looked on the forums tried<br/> tag but that did not work, so i added \n that did not work either but will just show you the end of line, so sorry trying to figure it out

Comment: You can try like this by use of [negated class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated): [`<a\s[^>]*?href="(http[^"?]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/mX6tW8/2)

Comment: Hello Bobble bubble you hit that one on the head; Now i get a very clean output Thank You some much

Answer (score 1):

Regex is really the wrong tool for the job. Doing a basic string split will get you exactly what you want.

```
def beforeQuestionMrk(inputStr):
    return inputStr.split("?")[0]

url = "https://search.yahoo.com/sometext"
url2 = "https://search.yahoo.com/search?p=Fetty+Wap&fr=fp-tts&"

print(beforeQuestionMrk(url))
print(beforeQuestionMrk(url2))

#https://search.yahoo.com/sometext
#https://search.yahoo.com/search
```

If you *really* wanted wanted to use regex I suppose you could fo the following:

```
import re

def getBeforeQuestRegex(inputStr):
    return re.search(r"(.+?\?|.+)", inputStr).group(0)


print(getBeforeQuestRegex("https://search.yahoo.com/search?p=Fetty+Wap&amp;fr=fp-tts&"))
print(getBeforeQuestRegex("https://search.yahoo.com/sometext"))

#https://search.yahoo.com/search?
#https://search.yahoo.com/sometext
```

Comment: Guys thank you so much you have already answered my question, I really appreciate it, I was trying something close to what you did / actually that is what i was trying just before I posted the question, And yes I could have used the split too, just wanted it be as succinct as possible. Thank you so much you guys are the best

Answer (score 0):

I agree with other answer, that using regexp here is not a solution, especially because there my be any number of parameters before opening of the `<a>` tag and href parameter, there can be a new line in between too.

but, answering to the initial question:

'*', '+', and '?' qualifiers are all greedy - they match as much text as possible

that's why there are non-greedy versions of them:

'*?', '+?' and '??'

Comment: Does  ?? Mean a literal question mark may appear 0 or one time

Answer (score 0):

Bobble bubbles solution above worked very well for me;

"You can try like this by use of negated class: ]*?href="(http[^"?]+)"<- bobbles answer.

url looks like this

https://search.yahoo.com/search?p=Justin+Bieber&fr=fp-tts&fr2=p:fp,m:tn,ct:all......

or it could be something like this 
https://www.yahoo.com/style/5-joyful-bob-ross-tees-202237009.html

objective was to extract full url if there was no literal ? in it, but if it did to stop just before the literal ?.

was Bobble Bubbles answer and works very cleanly, does what I wanted done, Again thank you for everyone in participating in this discussion, really appreciate it.